# SQL query for Bill of Materials to get levels of components

Tags: sql

I have got data that contains

| parent_id | child_id | parent_desc | child_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 24 | AA | BB |
| 123 | 81 | AA | ZZ |
| 24 | 32 | BB | EE |
| 32 | 45 | EE | DD |
| 45 | 57 | DD | FF |
| 57 | 62 | FF | GG |
| 62 | 7 | GG | FA |
| 81 | 9 | ZZ | GA |

What I want to achieve is to have a BOM explosion of it.
What I have come up is the below code:

```
     create table test
        ( SurrogateKey bigint, ForeignKey bigint,mat_desc varchar,comp_desc varchar );
        
        insert into test
        values 
        ( 123, 24,'AA','BB'),
        (123,81,'AA','ZZ'),
        ( 24, 32,'BB','EE'),
        ( 32, 45,'EE','DD'),
        ( 45, 57,'DD', 'FF'),
        ( 57, 62,'FF','GG'),
        ( 62, 7,'GG','FA'),
        (81,9,'ZZ','GA');
With traversal as 
( SELECT test.SurrogateKey OriginKey,
         ForeignKey,mat_desc,comp_desc
    FROM test
    WHERE SurrogateKey = 123 -- this first portion of the query generates the beginning set of records.
 UNION ALL
  SELECT traversal.OriginKey,
         test.ForeignKey,traversal.mat_desc,test.comp_desc
    FROM test
      INNER JOIN traversal
        ON test.SurrogateKey = traversal.ForeignKey -- we join back to the result set generated in the previous iteration of the recursion until no more nodes to travel to
)
select * from traversal
```

That is giving me a result:

| parent_id | child_id | parent_desc | child_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 24 | AA | BB |
| 123 | 81 | AA | ZZ |
| 123 | 32 | AA | EE |
| 123 | 9 | AA | GA |
| 123 | 45 | AA | DD |
| 123 | 57 | AA | FF |
| 123 | 62 | AA | GG |
| 123 | 7 | AA | FA |

But what I would like to achieve is to add column to see on which level the child is so thirst three rows would look like this, and so on

| parent_id | child_id | parent_desc | child_desc | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 24 | AA | BB | 1 |
| 123 | 81 | AA | ZZ | 1 |
| 123 | 32 | AA | EE | 2 |
| 123 | 9 | AA | GA |  |
| 123 | 45 | AA | DD |  |
| 123 | 57 | AA | FF |  |
| 123 | 62 | AA | GG |  |
| 123 | 7 | AA | FA |  |

Maybe someone has got idea, how to solve this. Maybe some window function, or how to come up with some counter to have it using recursive cte
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to enumerate the rows based on the tree-depth.  You correctly recognize that you can do this with a recursive CTE.

The syntax for recursive CTEs varies depending on the databases, but the idea is:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t.SurrogateKey, t.ForeignKey, t.mat_desc, t.comp_desc, t.mat_desc as orig_mat_desc, 1 as lev
      from test t
      where not exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.comp_desc = t.mat_desc)
      union all
      select t.SurrogateKey, t.ForeignKey, t.mat_desc, t.comp_desc, cte.orig_mat_desc, 1 + lev
      from cte join
           test t
           on cte.comp_desc = t.mat_desc
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1eb10580006d698e29ce866dcc48ebad) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

WITH Dr (depth, lineage, code, Father, childnum, qty, Whse, Curr, Price, parent) AS
(
SELECT
CAST(2 AS INTEGER) AS depth,
((CASE WHEN LEN(ITT1.childnum) = 2 THEN '1' ELSE '10' END) + CAST(ITT1.childnum AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '-') AS lineage,
ITT1.code,
ITT1.father,
ITT1.childnum,
ITT1.Quantity,
ITT1.Warehouse,
ITT1.Currency,
ITT1.Price,
ITT1.father AS parent
FROM ITT1
WHERE ITT1.father = 'your-item-father-code'
UNION ALL
SELECT
(Dr.depth + 1) AS depth,
(Dr.lineage + (CASE WHEN LEN(ITT1.childnum) = 2 THEN '1' ELSE '10' END) + CAST(ITT1.childnum AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '-') AS lineage,
ITT1.code,
ITT1.father,
ITT1.childnum,
ITT1.Quantity,
ITT1.Warehouse,
ITT1.Currency,
ITT1.Price,
Dr.code AS parent
FROM Dr
INNER JOIN ITT1 ON ITT1.father = Dr.code
WHERE ITT1.father <> ITT1.code
)
SELECT
d.lineage AS id,
d.code AS Item,
i1.ItemName AS 'Item Description',
i1.InvntryUom AS UoM,
d.qty AS Quantity,
d.Whse,
d.Curr,
d.Price,
d.depth AS Depth,
d.parent,
i1.TreeType AS 'BOM Type',
(SELECT i2.ItmsGrpNam FROM OITB i2 WHERE i1.ItmsGrpCod = i2.ItmsGrpCod) AS GroupName
FROM
Dr d
INNER JOIN
OITM i1 ON d.code = i1.ItemCode
ORDER BY
lineage;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).